# TAGLIB - An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, taglib-sharp

I have a small console app that browses through a set of folders and tries to set the ID3Tag properties.

ScrPathn Album and Artist are String constants.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
            List<string> dirs = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateDirectories(SrcPath));

            foreach (var dir in dirs)
            {
                string ParentDirOfFile = dir.Substring(dir.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir));
                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    string filename = Path.GetFileName(file); 
                    string destfile = Path.Combine(SrcPath, ParentDirOfFile + "_" + filename);
                    var fs = new FileStream(destfile, FileMode.Open);
                    using (var tagFile = TL.File.Create(new TL.StreamFileAbstraction(destfile, fs, fs)))
                    {
                        tagFile.Tag.Album = Album;
                        tagFile.Tag.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(destfile);
                        tagFile.Tag.AlbumArtists = new string[] { Artist };
                        tagFile.Save();
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

At the save step I get :

System.StackOverflowException was unhandled
Message: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

I'm using the latest version from TagLig which I installed via NuGet. 
Any sugggestions ?

EDIT.
No extra info is given by VS.

Changed code to split up read an write streams.

```
var readfs = new FileStream(destfile, FileMode.Open);
var writefs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(SrcPath, "_" + ParentDirOfFile + "_" + filename), FileMode.Create);
using (var tagFile = TL.File.Create(new TL.StreamFileAbstraction(destfile, readfs, writefs)))
```

Same error and an empty new file gets created.

Comment: Does it throw on the first time it hits the save?

Comment: Yes. At the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I quite understand your code but I know that here this simpler version does indeed work:

```
    using (var tagFile = TagLib.File.Create(destfile))
    {
        tagFile.Tag.Album = Album;
        tagFile.Tag.Title = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(destfile);
        tagFile.Tag.AlbumArtists = new string[] { Artist };
        tagFile.Save();
    }
```